# SSH configuration: override the default username

Tags: unix, ssh, ssh-config

Is it possible to configure `ssh` to know what my username should be?

By default it uses the current username, which is not correct in my case.

I'm on a loaner laptop, and my username is `loaner`, but I want to tell `ssh` that my username is `buck`.

Bonus points: my username at home is bgolemon. If I could configure the username per-host that would be even better.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: This is such a good question!

Comment: accepted answer here is better quality than superuser ones: includes global (default) user directive use and comments added make directive priorities clear

Comment: More about ssh config priorities, default and host-specific users and such: https://therootcompany.com/blog/ssh-defaults-config-and-priorities/

Answer (score 605):

Create a file called `config` inside `~/.ssh`. Inside the file you can add:

```
Host *
    User buck
```

Or add

```
Host example
    HostName example.net
    User buck
```

The second example will set a username and is hostname specific, while the first example sets a username only. And when you use the second one you don't need to use `ssh example.net`; `ssh example` will be enough.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that according to `man ssh_config`: `Since the first obtained value for each parameter is used, more host-specific declarations should be given near the beginning of the file, and general defaults at the end.` So the `Host *` section should probably go at the end.

Comment: It is worth noting that config file will be processed in top-to-bottom fashion, populating each field (User, HostName...) and _skipping_ repeated fields if multiple Host directives are matched. If you define `Host *`, `User jdoe` at the top, and then define `Host example`, `HostName abc.example.com`, `User root`, attempting `ssh example` will be the same as if you entered `ssh jdoe@abc.example.com`. In order to define ssh defaults (ie. `User root`), `Host *` directive needs to be _at the bottom_ of config file.

Comment: Also, don't forget chmod 600 on .ssh/config

Comment: Note that if there are multiple hostnames that the server is accessible by (or if you want the same default username for multiple servers), you should change the first line to `Host server1.local example.net *.example.org` and just get rid of the `HostName` line.

Answer (score 53):

If you only want to [ssh](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201) a few times, such as on a borrowed or shared computer, try:

```
ssh buck@hostname
```

or

```
ssh -l buck hostname
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already familiar with this. It seems redundant to specify buck@host when it's *always* buck@host. I'm trying to find a method to represent this information in a configuration file.

Comment: Have you considered something as simple as alias sshhostname='ssh buck@hostname'?

Comment: Yes, I have. Learath2's answer is exactly what I was looking for. I can check this into my dotfiles repository and not worry about it ever again.

Comment: I took the alias root because I connect to machines for different clients, where my username is different in each client environment. Another approach I suppose would be to have different local shell environments to set the ssh and related settings for each client. Or a VM per client.

Answer (score 8):

If you have multiple references to a particular variable i.e. User or IdentityFile, **the first entry in the ssh config file always takes precedence**, if you want something specific then put it in first, anything generic put it at the bottom.

Comment: This is *exactly* what I'm trying to figure out! Just move my `Host *` to the end of the file and everything works like I want.

Answer (score 6):

`man ssh_config` says

> **User**
>
> Specifies the user to log in as.  This can be useful when a
>   different user name is used on different machines.  This saves the
>                trouble of having to remember to give the user name on the command line.

Comment: "Identity" in this case is equivalent to the usual usage of "password". This is the data which authenticates you, but doesn't help specify who you are trying to authenticate _as_.

Comment: Oops. There's a user setting in there as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Ruby gem that interfaces your `ssh` configuration file which is called [`sshez`](http://rubygems.org/gems/sshez).

All you have to do is `sshez <alias> username@example.com -p <port-number>`, and then you can connect using `ssh <alias>`. It is also useful since you can list your aliases using `sshez list` and can easily remove them using `sshez remove alias`.