# Can I start a JSch session without a username and password?

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am using JSch in my Android app and I'd like to create a SSH connect without initially providing a username and password.  I can connect if I provide a username and password, but I get a username is not given" error from JSch if I do not provide a username.

This is what I have tried to connect without providing the username and password.

```
private class ConnectSSH extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... a) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession("192.168.1.42");
            session.setPort(22);
            session.connect();
            Channel channelssh = (Channel)session.openChannel("exec");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            InputStream commandOutput = channelssh.getInputStream();
            channelssh.connect();
            int readByte = commandOutput.read();
            while(readByte != 0xffffffff){
               sb.append((char)readByte);
               readByte = commandOutput.read();
            }
            channelssh.disconnect();
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Error - " + e;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Will my only option be to change the source code of JSch to allow this, compile to a jar, and then import that?

Comment: AFAIK, the username requirement comes as much from `sshd` as anything else. How have you configured your SSH daemon such that it does not require a username?

Comment: In theory, you can assign a default username for your ssh daemon (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197559/ssh-configuration-override-the-default-username)  so you wouldn't have to provide it. But in this case, it's a sshd configuration.

Another thing is the situation where someone starts a ssh connection and provide the username after that. In this case, I think JSch won't support this option.

Comment: Thanks Leo.  I'm referring to terminal emulators like Putty, that require a username and password after the connection is made.  Or is the connection not actually made until a username and password is given?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSch `Session` class constructor needs to have the username filled.

But it's the `UserAuth` implementation that ultimately decides what username is used.

So you can extend for example `UserAuthPassword` to assign the actual username to `.username` field at the start of `.start()` method.

```
class UserAuthUsernamePassword extends UserAuthPassword {

  public boolean start(Session session) throws Exception {
    this.username = "real_username";
    return super.start(session);
  }

}
```

And you just pass a dummy value to `username` argument of `Session` constructor.